# Como obter os valores de uma array apartir de uma key

Tags: php, array, loop, foreach

Preciso obter os valores ( $src ), dentro desse foreach, de cada key separadamente nesse array:

```
<?php

   foreach( get_post_gallery( $post->id, false ) as $key => $src ) { 

    echo $key; //resultado:  link, size - ids         - src
    echo $src; //resultado:  file, full - 61,59,57,41 - Array
   }

?>
```

**Esse é o array completo no `var_dump();`**

```
<?php
array(4) { 
    ["link"]=> string(4) "file" 
    ["size"]=> string(4) "full" 
    ["ids"]=> string(11) "61,59,57,41" 
    ["src"]=> array(4) { 
        [0]=> string(83) "http://localhost/1.jpg" 
        [1]=> string(94) "http://localhost/2.jpg" 
        [2]=> string(62) "http://localhost/3.jpg" 
        [3]=> string(68) "http://localhost/4.jpg" 
    }
} 
?>
```

> > UPDATE
> >
> > ### Queria poder montar assim o resultado:

```
 <?php
    array(4) { 
        ["link"]=> string(4) "file" 
        ["size"]=> string(4) "full" 

        ["ids"]=> array(4) { 
            [0]=> string(83) "61" 
            [1]=> string(94) "59" 
            [2]=> string(62) "57" 
            [3]=> string(68) "41" 
        }

        ["src"]=> array(4) { 
            [0]=> string(83) "http://localhost/1.jpg" 
            [1]=> string(94) "http://localhost/2.jpg" 
            [2]=> string(62) "http://localhost/3.jpg" 
            [3]=> string(68) "http://localhost/4.jpg" 
        }
    } 
    ?>
```

Comment: Alguma alma caridosa poderia ajudar?

Comment: Você pode fazer um novo foreach() dentro do src

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode imprimir a chave e o valor do array, verificando se alguma das chaves é um array com `is_array()`, no caso `src` e então fazer um `implode()` para exibir todos os itens.

```
<?php
    $arr = ['link' => 'file', 'size' => 'full', 'ids' => '61,59,57,41',
            'src' => ['http://localhost/1.jpg', 
                      'http://localhost/2.jpg', 
                      'http://localhost/3.jpg',
                      'http://localhost/4.jpg']
            ];

foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
    if($key == 'ids'){
        $arr['id'] = explode(',', $value);
    }

    if(!is_array($value)){
        echo "$key: ".  $value .'<br>';
    }
}

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($arr);
```

Saída:

```
Array
(
    [link] => file
    [size] => full
    [ids] => 61,59,57,41
    [src] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://localhost/1.jpg
            [1] => http://localhost/2.jpg
            [2] => http://localhost/3.jpg
            [3] => http://localhost/4.jpg
        )

    [id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 61
            [1] => 59
            [2] => 57
            [3] => 41
        )
)
```

Comment: @Lollipop pode fazer outro `foreach` dessa vez iterando `$v` no lugar do `implode()`.

Comment: @Lollipop, assim? `foreach($arr as $k => $v) {
 if(is_array($v)){
  echo 'links:<br>';
  foreach($v as $link){
   echo $link .'<br>';
  }
 }else{
  echo "$k:".  $v .'<br>';
 }
}
`

Comment: @Lollipop como um array?

Comment: @Lollipop `61` esta ligado a `http://localhost/1.jpg`, `59` a `http://localhost/2.jpg` isso?

Comment: @Lollipop veja se é isso

Comment: @Lollipop alterei a resposta.

Comment: Que bom que funcinou :)

Answer (score 0):

Pode ser dessa forma:

```
foreach( get_post_gallery( $post->id, false ) as $key => $src ) { 
    echo $key; //resultado:  link, size - ids         - src
    foreach($src as $valor){
        echo $valor->campo;
    }
}
```

Ou se não houver campo, faça da seguinte maneira

```
foreach( get_post_gallery( $post->id, false ) as $key => $src ) { 
    $i = 0;
    echo $key; //resultado:  link, size - ids         - src
    foreach($src as $valor){
        echo $valor[$i];
        $i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: : Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Dá um print_r() na $src, pra ver o retorno... qual das opções você ajustou? E acho que ali no get, você pode deixar apenas $src... sem o key

Comment: `Array ( 
[0] => link [1] => size 
[2] => ids 
[3] => src 
) 
file full 61,59,57, 41 
Array ( 
 [0] => http://localhost/1.jpg 
 [1] => http://localhost/2.jpg 
 [2] => http://localhost/3.jpg 
 [3] => http://localhost/4.jpg 
)`